# Django loops in HTML not going in order

Tags: html, django, loops

I have this block of code in my HTML template:

```
<main role="main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center pt-5">welcome to my blogs</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2>my latest blog</h2>
        <hr/>
        {% for e in allblogs.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' e.id %}"><h1>{{ e.title }}</h1></a>
        <h6>{{ e.pretty_time }}</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="{{ e.image.url }}">
            <p>{{ e.summary }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
```

How come I got the output `/blog/2` displayed first then `/blog/1` ?  ain't e loops from 1 first?  I couldn't find the answer.

Output:

```
<a href="/blog/2/"><h1>second blog</h1></a>
        <h6>Jun 26 2018</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="/media/image/ben-tatlow-635718-unsplash.jpg">
            <p>second blog with new picturefirst blog pictures in something is fun to learn, but it takes lots of t</p>

        <a href="/blog/1/"><h1>first blog</h1></a>
        <h6>Jun 26 2018</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="/media/image/aaron-burden-649463-unsplash.jpg">
            <p>first blog pictures in something is fun to learn, but it takes lots of time, at same time I would ha</p>

        <a href="/blog/3/"><h1>third blog</h1></a>
        <h6>Jun 26 2018</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="/media/image/caleb-lucas-434609-unsplash.jpg">
            <p>even more pictures first blog pictures in something is fun to learn, but it takes lots of time, at s</p>
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

# Create your views here.
def allblogs(request):
    allblogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'allblogs':allblogs})

def blog_detail(request, blog_id):
    blogdetail=get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', {'blog': blogdetail})
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/")
    text_body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def summary(self):
        return self.text_body[:100]

    def pretty_time(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

Comment: What is the view you use for this template?

Comment: I think the problem is that you write logic that should be *in* the view, in the template: the `order_by`.

Comment: Please share the (relevant) models and views.

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

# Create your views here.
def allblogs(request):
    allblogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'allblogs':allblogs})

def blog_detail(request, blog_id):
    blogdetail=get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', {'blog': blogdetail})

Comment: Please delete your question from the answers section, and try @UtkucanBıyıklı answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the output `/blog/2` first then `/blog/1` from the code below. Given that code, shouldn't `blog/1` be output before `blog/2` from my loop?

HTML template:

```
<main role="main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center pt-5">welcome to my blogs</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2>my latest blog</h2>
        <hr/>
        {% for e in allblogs.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' e.id %}"><h1>{{ e.title }}</h1></a>
        <h6>{{ e.pretty_time }}</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="{{ e.image.url }}">
            <p>{{ e.summary }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

# Create your views here.
def allblogs(request):
    allblogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'allblogs':allblogs})

def blog_detail(request, blog_id):
    blogdetail=get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', {'blog': blogdetail})
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/")
    text_body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def summary(self):
        return self.text_body[:100]

    def pretty_time(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

Output:

```
<a href="/blog/2/"><h1>second blog</h1></a>
        <h6>Jun 26 2018</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="/media/image/ben-tatlow-635718-unsplash.jpg">
            <p>second blog with new picturefirst blog pictures in something is fun to learn, but it takes lots of t</p>

        <a href="/blog/1/"><h1>first blog</h1></a>
        <h6>Jun 26 2018</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="/media/image/aaron-burden-649463-unsplash.jpg">
            <p>first blog pictures in something is fun to learn, but it takes lots of time, at same time I would ha</p>

        <a href="/blog/3/"><h1>third blog</h1></a>
        <h6>Jun 26 2018</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid" height="400" width="300" src="/media/image/caleb-lucas-434609-unsplash.jpg">
            <p>even more pictures first blog pictures in something is fun to learn, but it takes lots of time, at s</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use order_by method in view.

```
#views.py
def allblogs(request):
    allblogs = Blog.objects.all().order_by("id")
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'allblogs':allblogs})
```